# Value of limit with integral involved in it

Tags: integration, limits

The question is given by my friend. The problem  is $$L=\lim _{n\to \infty} \int _0 ^1  x^{10}\sin (nx)  dx $$ so what i did was  using by parts method. The relation I get for same thing with $x^8$ is in place of $10$ is that same integral can be written as $\frac {\sin (n)}{n}-\frac {9}{n}(\int _0^1 x^8\sin (nx) $....t. Then continuing we go to an integral of $\sin (nx)=\frac {1-\cos (n)}{n} $After going back with it we have limit as $0$ . But my friend says answer isnt $0$ . Even if we think logically we can see it to be $0$ Wheres the mistake?.Thanks

Comment: If you show your work, we might be able to find any errors. In particular, I find that sin(n)/n suspicious.

Comment: I also think the limit is zero. I played around with Desmos and I would like to see your friend's argument why it wouldn't be

Comment: It almost 2 pages so thats like tooooooo much to type

Comment: Basically i found relarion for x10,x8◂,▸x10,x8 so that sin is in picture

Answer (score 5):

You are right, the limit is $0$.

$$\int_0^1 x^{10}\sin (nx)\,dx = \biggl[x^{10}\frac{1-\cos (nx)}{n}\biggr]_0^1 - \frac{10}{n} \int_0^1 x^9\bigl(1 - \cos (nx)\bigr)\,dx.$$

We can estimate the remaining integral by $\frac{20}{n}$ using $\lvert x^9\rvert \leqslant 1$ and $\lvert 1-\cos (nx)\rvert \leqslant 2$, and thus we obtain

$$\biggl\lvert\int_0^1 x^{10}\sin (nx)\,dx\biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{22}{n}.$$

The specific function $x^{10}$ is irrelevant, it holds for every integrable function $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x)\sin (nx)\,dx = 0,$$

that is part/a consequence of the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 2):

You are right the limit is 0, but your calculation should be
$$\int_0^1 x^{10}\sin(nx)\,dx = \left[x^{10}\left(-\frac{\cos nx}{n}\right)\right]_0^1+ \frac{10}{n}\int_0^1 x^{9}\cos(nx)\,dx$$
which tends to 0 as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Basically i found relarion for $x^{10} ,x^8$ so that sin is in picture